# What is "this" in the factory function of requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm studying the following code, but having trouble understand the keyword *this*.

Is the "*this*" in *e.stunHost && this.init()* the same as *init: function() { this.answer = "" }*

Thanks.

The following code is stripped from a module about RrcPeerConnection.

```
define("WebRtcPeer", ["jquery", "Logger"], function(e, t) {
        "use strict";
            var i = function(e) {
            e.stunHost && this.init()
            };
        return i.prototype = {
            stunHost: null,
            init: function() {
                this.answer = ""
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are same, all point to function i.

Comment: I tried _var i = function () { return this };_ in jsfiddle, but it return the _Window object_. Are they different?

Comment: check nmrony's link, you will understand why here this point to Window, it's not use keyword "new", find prototype chain to window.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a special keyword that refers to the current object. To learn about `this` keyword in javascript check the link [`this` and Object prototype](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md)